# GoogleSignIn - Framework AppAuth not found, framework is red Swift

Tags: swift, google-signin, appauth

Sort of new to coding. Read through every other post and still getting the same error where running build after following the GoogleSignIn tutorial gives me an error saying 'Framework not found AppAuth'.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL7eF.png)
[framework in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNRqc.png)

List of stuff I have tried:

1. Reinstalling GoogleSignIn with pod deintegrate, pod install
2. Matching deployment target in both Project>General and Pod>General (to iOS 14.1)
3. Checking to make sure search paths are connected
   [framework search path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix613.png)
4. Made AppAuth location relative to SDK
5. Made sure .workspace is open

Am working from an m1 chip, not sure if that matters. Terminal is open in rosetta because of issues installing pods using silicon. Please let me know what code you would like me to add.

Comment: Update. Turns out some frameworks are not working on the new M1 MacBook chips because the simulator in Xcode has some compatability issues with them. 

Instead of trying to run your code to the simulator, simply run your code to a physical device through USB (like an iPhone) or select the 'my Mac' simulator. These seem too work without any problems.